# Script for database structure creation

Tags: oracle, corda

Given that in our environment database structures (tables, views, etc) are not allowed to be created by application user (runtime), is there any script available to do that prior to Node startup?

PS. It's a Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood correctly, but check [knex.js](https://knexjs.org/) out.

After the installing knex.js, (npm install knex.js --save) you need to make the connection:

```
var conn = knex({
  client: 'oracledb',
  connection: {
    host: your-host,
    user: your-user,
    password: your-password,
    database: your-db,
  }
});
```

Example of creating sample user table:

```
function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', function (t) {
    t.bigincrements('id').primary()
    t.string('email').notNullable()
    t.string('password', 64)
    t.integer('state').notNullable().defaultTo(0)
    t.timestamp('lastlogin').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    t.timestamp('regdate').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    t.biginteger('sevdeskId')
    t.index('sevdeskId', 'sevdeskId')
    t.string('invoiceEmail', 100)
    t.string('firstName')
    t.string('lastName')
    t.string('companyName')
    t.string('phoneNumber', 16)
    t.boolean('newsletterSubscription').defaultTo(false)
  })}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In fact, I was referring to the Node structure (node_transactions, vault_states, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it. Use `CordaService`. Create Service called DBStartup Service. These are singleton Classes and loaded once at the time of node startup. In Its Constructor, you can get access to the `jdbcsession` from the `servicehub` or `appservicehub` read your sql script and execute using the jdbcsession you just got.

Create this service as a separate module, and inject the service jar as cordaApp in the nodes you want this functionality.

Comment: In fact, I was referring to the Node structure (node_transactions, vault_states, etc).

Comment: they are created by default. no?

Comment: Due to policy rules in our firm, database structures are not allowed to be created/modified by applications at runtime. Application users don't have permissions to do that, so, I was wondering whether there's a script to be executed by the DBA to create the node database structure.

Comment: Just export the table schema of the existing database before and hand it over to your DBA to execute it. There are many tools that can help you do that like squirrel, toad, etc.

Comment: Ok. We've already taken this approach, but just checking if there were a script built to that, or whether the Node included some custom info at startup. Thanks.